# php mysql show friends' posts

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to show friends' posts?

Each user can have maximum 5000 friends.

Steps:

1) mysql retrieve 5000 friends' usernames.

2) store 5000 friends' usernames in a php array.

3) `SELECT posts, datatime FROM tbl_posts WHERE username IN ($array) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;`

Question : Let's say zac1987 is 5000th item in php array. If the 10 latest posts are posted by zac1987, does mysql need to waste times to loop through 5000 items to determine whether or not the post is posted by him? So if I want to show 10 latest posts, does mysql need to loop through 5000 friends x 10 posts = 50,000 items? And every 5 seconds need to check if there is any new posts, so it means every 5 seconds need to loop 50,000 items? Is there any method to prevent so many looping/filtering items process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    friend f
JOIN    post p
ON      p.author = f.friend_id
WHERE   f.user_id = $myuserid
ORDER BY
        p.post_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

You should create indexes on `post (post_date)`, `post (author)`, `friend (friend_id, user_id)`

Depending on the cardinality, `MySQL` will either make `post` leading in the join (in which case the first index will be used) or make `friend` leading (in which case it will gather all friends' posts and sort them).

Comment: WOW, never know I can skip holding 5000 friends in array by using join method, thank you very much. What if I want to make `post` leading in the join? I want to show 10 latest posts, I don't want to show the posts that posted by 10 latest friends.

Comment: @zac1987: you may use `STRAIGHT_JOIN` however you better let `MySQL` decide. The query will show `10` latest posts since you order by `p.post_date` anyway. Which table is leading or driven does not affect the semantics of the query.